# Facebook API - Is it possible to email users when they click "Become a Fan"?

Tags: facebook

I want to do the following, but not sure if it is possible with the current API.  The only thing I found in the AP is the ability to tell if a FB user is a fan.  Here goes:

When a user clicks the become a fan button, it sends a custom message (email or facebook email) with url to redeem a code for a free song. The code is obtained from my own custom DB.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's definitely possible to turn them on after they've become a fan! http://www.dweebist.com/2010/02/become-a-fan/